# on_message won't work with command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm not sure if the code won't work because of the `on_message(ctx)` or not, either way, is what I have done:

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
import pymongo 
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

mango_url = "mongodb+srv://<usernamehere>:<password>@discordbot.kllv6.mongodb.net/discordbot? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority"
cluster = MongoClient(mango_url)
db = cluster["discordbot"]
collection = db["discordbot"]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is online")


@client.command()
async def _ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('discord sucks :(')

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    author_id = ctx.author.id
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id 
    author = ctx.author
    user_id = {"_id": author_id}

    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return

    if ctx.author.bot:
        return

    if(collection.count_documents({}) == 0):
        user_info = {"_id": author_id, "GuildID": guild_id, "Level": 1, "XP": 0}
        collection.insert_one(user_info)

    if(collection.count_documents(user_id) == 0):
        user_info = {"_id": author_id, "GuildID": guild_id, "Level": 1, "XP": 0}
        collection.insert_one(user_info)

    exp = collection.find(user_id)
    for xp in exp:
        cur_xp = xp["XP"]

        new_xp = cur_xp + 1 

    collection.update_one({"_id": author_id}, {"$set":{"XP":new_xp}}, upsert=True)

    #await ctx.channel.send("1 xp up")

    lvl = collection.find(user_id)
    for levl in lvl:
        lvl_start = levl["Level"]

        new_level = lvl_start + 1

    if cur_xp >= round(5 * (lvl_start ** 4 / 5)):
        collection.update_one({"_id": author_id}, {"$set":{"Level":new_level}}, upsert=True)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{author.name} has leveled up to {new_level}!")

        await bot.process_commands(ctx)



client.run("token")
```

If I remove everything inside the `on_message(ctx)` (also the event) then it works.

I have tried everything but it won't work.

Example:

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

That does not work either because I am using `ctx` not `message`. I think...

If you have an answer to this please help me with this.

Comment: Does it throw any error or just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shows a straight error.

When we use `event` then the argument: `message` is used and then we use `command()` then the argument: `ctx` is used.

You are using the `ctx` argument for an event in your bot. It won't simply work.

You need to change it to `message`.

Also the statement:

```
await bot.process_command(ctx)
```

Here too `ctx` has to be changed to `message` and it should be used with `else` and not inside `if`.

Your bot is not `bot` variable but is `client`. So replace the `bot` in `on_message` to `client`

After all of the above changes the code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author_id = message.author.id
    guild_id = message.guild.id 
    author = message.author
    user_id = {"_id": author_id}

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if(collection.count_documents({}) == 0):
        user_info = {"_id": author_id, "GuildID": guild_id, "Level": 1, "XP": 0}
        collection.insert_one(user_info)

    if(collection.count_documents(user_id) == 0):
        user_info = {"_id": author_id, "GuildID": guild_id, "Level": 1, "XP": 0}
        collection.insert_one(user_info)

    exp = collection.find(user_id)
    for xp in exp:
        cur_xp = xp["XP"]

        new_xp = cur_xp + 1 

    collection.update_one({"_id": author_id}, {"$set":{"XP":new_xp}}, upsert=True)

    await message.channel.send("1 xp up")

    lvl = collection.find(user_id)
    for levl in lvl:
        lvl_start = levl["Level"]

        new_level = lvl_start + 1

    if cur_xp >= round(5 * (lvl_start ** 4 / 5)):
        collection.update_one({"_id": author_id}, {"$set":{"Level":new_level}}, upsert=True)
        await message.channel.send(f"{author.name} has leveled up to {new_level}!")
    
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

---

Hope this helps. Thank You! :D

Comment: You're still using `ctx` in the `process_commands`, you might want to update that. Also, OPs bot is called `client`, not `bot`. Also also, putting the `process_commands` in the else clause will lead the bot to ignore any commands if the user happens to level up in the same message. An edge case for sure, but it should be considered nontheless and the fix is as easy as putting the line outside of any block on the function's top level

Comment: Fine. Let me make the necessary changes.

Comment: it finally works!!! You are all so nice to help me.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues with your `on_message` event:

1. `on_message` comes with a `message`, not a `ctx`
2. Your bot client is called `client`, not `bot`
3. The `process_commands` line is indented too far. It needs to be on the outmost indentation layer of the event definition, otherwise it can end up not being triggered for each message, which leads the bot to ignore some or all commands (in your case, the only time the bot would recognize a command is if the user levelled up in the same message)

You can fix your code by making it something like the below:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author_id = message.author.id
    guild_id = message.guild.id 
    author = message.author
    user_id = {"_id": author_id}

    if message.author.bot:
        return
    
    # rest of your code goes here

    # notice the indentation layer. This needs to be at the top layer of your function
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

---

Side note: you don't need to check if the message author is your bot separately, as the `message.author.bot` check will ignore it anyway

Comment: this helped allot! 
thank you !
I was getting really stressed
thanks for helping :)